# How to get ruby 2.0 Module#prepend in ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

What would be the equvivalent of Module#prepend in ruby 1.8?

Comment: It is a newly introduced feature in Ruby 2.0. If there were an equivalent already in Ruby 1.8, then there would not have been any need to introduce it in Ruby 2.0.

Comment: @guai what's your use case? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: As I have read in "whats new in ruby 2.0" there was a way to do that, but it was more verbose.

Comment: I want to override some methods of existing class at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `alias_method_chain` implementation in Rails.

http://codelevy.com/2013/02/26/ruby2.0-vs-alias_method_chain.html